# Bitbake fetch fails complaining that URL is not trusted

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded, recipe, yocto-recipe

When I add the gdbserver to the image using 'IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " gdbserver" ', Bitbake complain that the URL is not trusted and hence can't fetch as shown below.

```
WARNING: gdb-9.1-r0 do_fetch: Failed to fetch URL https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-9.1.tar.xz, attempting MIRRORS if available
ERROR: gdb-9.1-r0 do_fetch: The URL: 'https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-9.1.tar.xz' is not trusted and cannot be used
ERROR: gdb-9.1-r0 do_fetch: Bitbake Fetcher Error: FetchError('Unable to fetch URL from any source.', 'https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-9.1.tar.xz')
```

However I can download the tar file from the browser, so it's not security issue from network. How to whitelist this URL such that Bitbake can fetch gdb?

Thanks

Comment: There is a workaround, download it from browser then put it inside download repository of your yocto folder. Then add empty file named gdb-9.1.tar.xz.done. It should be okay.

Comment: @void_brain, Thanks for the reply. Currently I did the same think that you mentioned. In the mean time I am also looking if there is a fix for this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have all upstreams you desire to pull from in `BB_ALLOWED_NETWORKS`

[Variable Glossary - BB_ALLOWED_NETWORKS](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html?highlight=bb_allowed_networks#term-BB_ALLOWED_NETWORKS)